# can listbox show both key and value from dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, binding

I have a dictionary, there's a int property in MyClass
           `public Dictionary<MyClass, BitmapImage> MyList = new Dictionary<MyClass, BitmapImage>();` 
I want listbox to show images from this collection (like ItemsSource?) and to show each property in textboxes near each image, is that possible?

Comment: why dictionary? simply move BitmapImage into MyClass as a property.

Comment: Yes. Use ItemTemplate - a TextBox and Image.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary yes it is a better solution but I didn't manage to figure out how to do it both in xaml and in code, would you mind helping me?

Comment: sorry im not good at wpf binding . i just thought it would be better.

Comment: @NickShepard create a List<MyClass> with BitmapImage as a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code behind example:**

**C#:**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    PopulatePeople();
}

private void PopulatePeople()
{
   List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Bob " + i.ToString(), ImageAddress = "Images/peach.jpg" });
    }
   listBox.ItemsSource = persons;
 }
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox Name="listBox">            
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageAddress}" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

**MVVM example:**

[Download the example from OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D6BDF30773C16E01!2019&authkey=!AMYjUXMhlcp4S4o&ithint=file%2Czip).

It is better to use `DataTemplate` in `ListBox` to show `Image` and `TextBox`.

**Model:**

```
public class Person 
{
    public int IDPerson { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageAddress { get; set; }
}
```

You can fill your collection in constructor of ViewModel:

**ViewModel:**

```
public class YourViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
       get { return persons; }
       set
       {
          persons = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("Persons");
        }
     }

     public  YourViewModel()
     {  
        FillThePersons();
    }

    private void FillThePersons()
    {           
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Bob " + i.ToString(),      
            ImageAddress="Images/peach.jpg" });// Images is the name folder in your project
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">            
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageAddress}" Width="50" Height="50"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The following example one image to all items:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
   <ListBox.Resources>
      <BitmapImage x:Key="AnImage" UriSource="Images/yourImage.png" />
   </ListBox.Resources>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{StaticResource AnImage}" Width="50" Height="50"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
         </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you but how should i fill my collection? and how will images be different? @StepUp

Comment: why do I always have an exception NullReferenceException?
    ' CollectionsVm.ProtectionCollection pr = new CollectionsVm.ProtectionCollection();
            pr.ListHelmets.Add(new Helmet(){protection=7, Image="helmets.jpg"});
            pr.ListHelmets.Add(new Helmet() { protection = 5, Image = "helmets.jpg" }); '
''helmets'' is a folder that containts few images, is that right?
"Images" is string like ImageAdress in your code @StepUp

Comment: now my listbox shows smth really weird, it consists of one item without images and kinda empty textbox @StepUp

Comment: can you show the screenshot? i can't lauch project unf
that's what i got http://cs627722.vk.me/v627722797/2efaa/R8LDXDAQg1M.jpg  @StepUp

Comment: Thank you so much, I would've tick your answer as right one a dozen of times if I could! I made ImageAdress as BitmapImage and it works now. but now i've got another problem, when i had just items, not itemssource, drag and drop worked, but now it doesn't @StepUp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473707/some-mistake-with-drag-and-drop-an-item-from-listbox just code behind @StepUp

Comment: @NickShepard sorry that I show you MVVM example. Please use code behind example which I show in my updated answer. And your drag and drop should start working.